# Control the classpath ordering of jars in WEB-INF/lib on Tomcat 5?

Tags: java, tomcat, jar, classpath

I have a legacy web app running in Tomcat 5.0.

This web app has two jars in *WEB-INF/lib*, let's say **Foo-2.0.jar** and **Bar-2.0.jar**. **Bar-2.0.jar** actually includes a **Foo-1.0.jar** inside of it. Bar is also a dead project, meaning no upgrading, no source, but still important to the application.

The latest release of this application requires **Foo-2.0.jar** for some other stuff. Having both **Foo-1.0.jar** and **Foo-2.0.jar** in the classpath creates a conflict, specifically a *ClassDefNotFound* type of error, where a class that was later added in 2.0 cannot be found in 1.0, etc.

In Eclipse, the simple solution is to right click on your *Project*, click *Properties* > *Java Built Path* > *Order and Export* and to move **Foo-2.0.jar** above **Bar-2.0.jar** so it's resolved first.

How does one accomplish this type of classpath ordering for jars in *WEB-INF/lib* in Tomcat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put Foo-1.0.jar to $CATALINE_HOME/common/endorsed (or any other place where it will be loaded after Foo-2.0.jar).

Answer (score 35):

[Tomcat 5's classloading precedence](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/class-loader-howto.html) for webapps is roughly as follows: first the bootstrap/system (`JRE/lib`, then Tomcat's internal classes), then the webapp libraries (first `WEB-INF/classes`, then `WEB-INF/lib`), then the common libraries (first `Tomcat/common`, then `Tomcat/lib`) and finally the webapp-shared libraries (`Tomcat/shared`).

So to get `Foo-2.0.jar` loaded *before* `Bar-2.0.jar`, best what you can do is to move `Bar-2.0.jar` from `WEB-INF/lib` to `Tomcat/common` or `Tomcat/shared`.

The JAR's aren't loaded in alphabetic order of their name. At least, there's no spec which says that. Renaming them to change the alphabetical filename order makes no sense.

Comment: Georgy answered first, so I accepted his submission, but what you describe is exactly what I did to resolve the problem. Your link was especially helpful. **I encourage everyone to vote up this answer**.

Comment: You're welcome. Although I would point out that answers here are **not** by default ordered by answer date. At the moment of writing you can see at the topright of the user avatar that I answered this question 23 minutes ago and Georgy 15 minutes ago. You can change the ordering by one of the three tabs `oldest`, `newest` and `votes` righttop of the answers. The default is `votes`.

Comment: And, in the tooltip you can see the exact time. So I was actually first :o

Comment: Class Loader HOW-TO for Tomcat 8 https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html

Answer (score 4):

Strip **Foo-1.0.jar** out of **Bar-2.0.jar**. As it is, it's just trouble waiting to happen both for development(need to fudge the dev. environments) and for deployment.

Comment: I really think this is the best suggestion.   Repackage your bar-2.0.jar, otherwise you are just asking for headaches down the road.

Answer (score 1):

You don't, as this feature isn't available in Tomcat.  If both Foo-1.0.jar and Foo-2.0.jar are needed in the classpath at the same time, you will need some major classpath reorganization.

If Bar-2.0 can work with Foo-2.0, then the best thing to do would be to rebuild Bar-2.0 yourself without a Foo-1.0.jar inside of it.

Comment: There is no way to know if Bar-2.0 works with Foo-2.0 or not, and it's a massive, binary-only library with no test cases.

Comment: I believe the solution you are using has Bar-2.0 running with Foo-2.0, just in a kind of roundabout way.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set the Class-Path in the mainfest of the jar. http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/javaprogramming/JAR/basics/manifest.html
I can't really promise it will solve the problem, but can be worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

To have Foo-2.0.jar before Bar-2.0.jar, update the Bar-2.0.jar with the content of Foo-2.0.jar (overwrite already contained .class)and delete Foo-2.0.jar from the war.

-cp A.jar:B.jar has the effect, that content of A.jar is like a layer over B.jar. So you get the same effect with overwriting B.jar's content with A.jar's.

Answer (score -2):

This is a bit hacky but might work. Change the name of Foo-2.0.jar to be alphabetically ahead of Bar-2.0.jar, say AFoo-2.0.jar.