# What I have to do to guarantee that ccc.jar is loaded before aaa.jar?

Tags: java, jar, ear, websphere-6.1

Does somebody know in which order of precedence are the jars loaded?

Having several jars in **WEB-INF/lib** (in a **war** inside an **ear** in **WAS 6.1**).

Let's say **aaa.jar**, **bbb.jar**, **ccc.jar**. I have two different versions of a class **paq1.paq2.paq3.MyClass** inside **aaa.jar** and **ccc.jar**

The one inside **ccc.jar** is the correct one; the one in the **aaa.jar** is the wrong.

It seems that the wrong version is localized before the correct one.

Does somebody know what I have to do to guarantee that **ccc.jar** is loaded before **aaa.jar**?

(This is a simplification of a more real/complex problem, so renaming jars doesn't apply in this case).

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why does this matter? (I'm curious.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Control the classpath ordering of jars in WEB-INF/lib on Tomcat 5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021227/control-the-classpath-ordering-of-jars-in-web-inf-lib-on-tomcat-5)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate as it's about a different hosting platform and the answers on the other question are specific to that platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebSphere Application Server makes no guarantees about the ordering of JARs within `WEB-INF/lib`, and there is no option to force a particular ordering. I recommend removing duplicate classes and resources.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe the servlet specification guarantees any specific Classpath ordering for the jars in the lib-folder.  Hence you are looking at vendor specific functionality or - even worse - vendor specific accidental behavior, which tends to be very brittle.

If the bad class is in your deployment, the cure is removing the bad class definitions from your deployment.  I would suggest that your build procedure is responsible for this.

If the bad class is in WAS itself you can usually override it by putting jars in an extension folder in the server itself, not as part of your deployment.

Comment: Agree except for the last paragraph. The WebSphere solution would be to change the classloader policy to PARENT LAST. Overriding classes deployed with WebSphere is likely to break something else.

Answer (score 1):

JVM takes class from the first jar in class path, where appropriate class exists. All others are discarded. You can remove this jars from WEB-INF and put them directly to webserver's class path. But this will be ugly solution.