# Unable to connect to HIVE through JDBC from a webapp

Tags: java, tomcat, hadoop, jdbc, hive

I have used the JDBC api to connect to HIVE2 referring [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients#HiveServer2Clients-UsingJDBC), it was successful so for easy of access I thought of creating a webapp around it using JSP as front-end page to enter server name and query. While all parameters are resolved correctly from JSP page to servlet it throws an error while connecting to HIVE server its required
to place libthrift and hive JARS in WEB-INF/lib directory I placed in both WEB-INF/lib and classpath.

Issue is as hive jar comes first in WEB-INF/lib and as it does not have "org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocol.getScheme()" method I keep getting no such method error. I referred [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021227/control-the-classpath-ordering-of-jars-in-web-inf-lib-on-tomcat-5) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20678857/what-i-have-to-do-to-guarantee-that-ccc-jar-is-loaded-before-aaa-jar?lq=1) and moved the libthrift jar to WEB-INF/classes but it dint help:

> Jar versions: libthrift-0.9.3 and hive-0.4.1

Comment: Are you serious about the Hive version?? V0.4.1 was released in **2009**; Cloudera distibution ships with V1.2 (and they are notoriously cautious); and V2.0 is available.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter: Hi, I meant Hive2 in context of [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients#HiveServer2Clients-UsingJDBC) our hive server version is "hive-0.13"

Comment: Hive2 usually refers to "HiveServer2", the 2nd-generation JDBC service. Nothing to do with Hive version proper.

Comment: Ok... But it was working fine before... Just after trying to build web app it's failing

Comment: I guess the ordering in WEB-INF/lib is the problem as hive-0.4.1 jar does not have "Tprotocol.getScheme()" method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only your Hive version was more recent, you could...

- get a recent driver such as 
  http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hive/hive-jdbc/2.0.0/
- I mean the ***standalone*** JAR, to get rid of your CLASSPATH issues
- although that "standalone" promise is not 100% true because you still need a couple of extra Hadoop JARS, cf. [Where is Apache Hive JDBC driver for download?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36005061/where-can-i-find-apache-hive-jdbc-driver-for-download/36005379#36005379)

But alas, you cannot user a driver that is more recent that your server -- here V0.13, i.e. the last version without a "standalone" driver JAR.
So you've got a whole bunch of Hive JARs to collect, plus a couple of Hadoop JARs and various dependencies such as `libfb303-*.jar` and `libthrift-*.jar`

> $ unzip -l libthrift-0.9.2.jar | grep
>   org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocol.class
>
> 2958  11-05-2014 03:47   org/apache/thrift/protocol/TProtocol.class

Comment: Tried with this standalone jar got same issue, then removed all JARS and then added "hive-exec-0.12.0.jar", "hive-jdbc-0.12.0.jar" and "hive-service-0.13.1.jar" and tried to run the now getting this error: "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/conf/HiveConf$ConfVars"

Comment: Mixing JARs from different versions (here V0.12 and V0.13.1) is **not** a good idea... I guess your nickname is "daredevil"  :-0

Comment: Anyway, in my answer I was trying to tell you "softly" that your original message was about some missing Thrift libraries (from Facebook). The "soft" attempt has visibly failed so I will try again loudly: **Hive uses Thrift protocol, you must put the Thrift libraries** i.e. `libfb303-*.jar` and `libthrift-*.jar` **in the _CLASSPATH_ of your app** -- unless they are already bundled in a "standalone" driver; **but with V0.13 you cannot use a "standalone" driver**

Comment: :D sometimes softly does not work i guess... thanks... did as advised.. and its working now