# How do I change the order of jar files in the build classpath?

Tags: eclipse, grails, grails-2.3

I am using `Grails 2.3.x` and have an external jar file. I need to change the order of some of the jar files because of dependencies in the build path. I use Eclipse but I do not use Maven.

**How do I change the order of jar files in the build classpath?**

Comment: @Dónal I use gwt with grails and I want to use this plugin: https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery-plugins/wiki/DroppablePluginGettingStarted it requires to put the jar file before the gwt.jar file to work. How can I do that?

Comment: See if this helps ya: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021227/control-the-classpath-ordering-of-jars-in-web-inf-lib-on-tomcat-5

Comment: Is there not a similar feature like [Java Build Path](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-properties-build-path.htm) `Order` tab for a grails project?

Comment: Why are you trying to change the order? What are you trying to achieve by doing so?

Comment: I want to change the order because I need it because of dependencies.